# Installation of the crypto library "libpqcrypto"

Tags: c, ubuntu, compilation, installation, libcrypto

We are trying to install the library **libpqcrypto** for Ubuntu (since several days) following exactly the instructions on their [webpage](https://libpqcrypto.org). Unfortunately, we are not able to fix the error appearing during the installation:

```
cpucycles/amd64cpuspeed compiling 
# gcc -fPIC -Wall -march=native -mtune=native -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -fwrapv

cpucycles.c: In function ‘pqcpucycles_impl_persecond’:
cpucycles.c:20:12: error: ‘CTL_HW’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘CTL_PM’?
   oid[0] = CTL_HW;
            ^~~~~~
            CTL_PM
cpucycles.c:20:12: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
cpucycles.c:21:12: error: ‘HW_CPUSPEED’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   oid[1] = HW_CPUSPEED;
            ^~~~~~~~~~~
cpucycles/cpucycles.c compiler exited 1
```

---

Would you have any idea why this error is occurring or what it is telling us?

PS: We are running Ubuntu on a Mac using Parallels Desktop.

Comment: Yes, it (usually) means that you are missing an `#include <sys/sysctl.h>`. Please post the code part it refers to.

Comment: You can usually replace one of them with something like: `processors = atoi(getenv("NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS"));`